# Can't open Resharper's "bookmarks menu" (Ctrl + `)

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Can't open "bookmarks menu" when pressing `` [Ctrl + `] ``.

Can set bookmarks by pressing `[Ctrl + Shift + 1,2,3..]` but can't open list/menu of all setted bookmarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug when multiple bookmarks were setted with the same number.

Everything starts work again if you reset all bookmarks by pressing `[Ctrl + Shift + 1,2,3...]` consistently for all numbers from 1 to 9.

Comment: Same just happened to me, this fixed it

Answer (score 1):

bside's solution not helped in my situation (VS2017 PRO 15.9.16 + ReSharper Ultimate 2019.2.2). Bookmarks window not worked at all.

It appears that you should go to **Menu > Resharper > Navigate > Bookmarks** and choose **Clear All Bookmarks**.